# Adding a game timer

Tags: flash, flash-builder, flashcatalyst

Please guide me. We have created a game, its genre is mind/puzzle. The platform we used was flash catalyst. Now the problem is the game timer. How can we add timer to the game? Can flash builder do that? How? Thanks in advance for the information.

Answer (score 0):

i have found [this thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/881766) with a complete solution to your problem